# How to use converters without binding paths?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I have a Combobox whose ItemsSource is an **ObservableCollection of int** values.
My combobox itemtemplate consists on an image and a textblock which content is given by 2 converters.

How can I set this 2 bindings? The following code does not compile:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <Image Source="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource IntToImageConverter}}" Stretch="None" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource IntToStringConverter}}" />
          </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to remove the `,` so:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IntToImageConverter}}" Stretch="None" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IntToStringConverter}}" />
          </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```